# Get the teamproject collection from a WorkItem

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-workitem

I want to add the WebPageControl to a WorkItemType and need to define the Teamproject collection of the current Work Item as a path parameter of the URL. The WebPageControle shows a C# Webapplication. Is there a field like `System.Teamproject` or an other way that gives me the Teamproject collection? I know that the ID of the Work Item isn't unique to all collections and the area path includes only the Project but not the collection.

Comment: First of all, how are you planning to retrieve the work items because to do that you need to connect to a collection or project at first. Meaning, that you would already have a right instance of project/collection.

Comment: Good Point! I dont need to retrive the work item. I only need to know the collection because i have a database table with a column "collection/project" and i need to get the right datasets for the current work item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a field you can pass along to the page being called, but since the Process Template configuration is stored at the project level, you can customize the work item type definition and simply hard-code the uri to the project collection in the WebpageControl's properties.

There's also the option to update the process template before registering it to the Project Collection. Since each project collection has it's own Template library, you only need to update it when you update the template at the collection level in that case.

This is unfortunately something you'll have to do each time you create a new project or update a process template of an existing Team project. It should not be terribly hard to script though...

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a WorkItem object then you can do `wi.Store.[Collection].xxx`.

Once you have the store you can get all of the data.

Comment: That assumes he has access to the work item, but I don't think he has that when the page is being called.